# Remove duplicates only if both columns are the same - excel

Tags: excel

I would like to remove rows with duplicates only if two columns are the same:

A   B   C.

—————————.

AA  11  L.

AA  12  l.

BB  12  L.

AA  11  C.

Basically, I want to check if both, A and B are the same, if they are, remove duplicates.
So output is:

A   B   C.

—————————.

AA  11  L.

AA  12  L.

BB  12  L.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using the normal duplicate and maybe adding both values to a single cell and then checking for duplicates, but when trying to add them to same cell it doesn’t know what to do (string and a date)

Answer (score 1):

It is standard behavior of `Remove duplicates` function. Just uncheck cols what you not need to compare.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the data is like this:

[image]

My formula at D2 is `=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2;A2;$B$2:B2;B2)` and drag down.

Later on, you can filter in that column for any value **higher than 1** (a 2 means a second coincidence, a 3 a third coincidence, and so on) and delete all those rows)

Hope this helps

**IMPORTANT**: Please, note the sorting here is important, because the formula starts counting from first row of data, so if you change the order, what was the first coincidence could be now the second one, and then be deleted. Be aware of that.